# Type Casting for Formula as Output - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Been trying to get the following function to work:

```
function getRsiData(symbol) {
      var queryString = Math.random();
      var cellFunction = '=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://www.stockta.com/cgi-bin/analysis.pl?symb="'+ symbol +'"&mode=table&table=rsi&num1=1","table",7),1,2)';


  return cellFunction;
}
```

Basically, I would like to return cellFunction so that my spreadsheet will automatically show the output of the function. Currently it is showing the text. What would be the correct way to type cast it?

Comment: Are you using `setFormula()`   [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Answer (score 0):

First off, there should not be double quotes around those simple quotes. *Do not* write:

> " '+ symbol +' "

instead, do write:

> '+ symbol +'

Second... Whatever your main function is, it will need to include [setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) like this:

```js
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");     // replace B5 with whatever range you want
  cell.setFormula(getRsiData("AAPL")); // replace AAPL with another symbol
}
```

That's it, only 2 problems! I tested it with success. The value of B5 is now 71.89 in the first sheet. Here is an example of the full final code:

```js
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B5"); // replace B5 with whatever range you want
  cell.setFormula(getRsiData("AAPL")); // replace AAPL with another symbol
}

function getRsiData(symbol) {
  var queryString = Math.random();
  var cellFunction = '=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://www.stockta.com/cgi-bin/analysis.pl?symb=' + symbol + '&mode=table&table=rsi&num1=1","table",7),1,2)';
  return cellFunction;
}
```

Please let me know if you can make it work now